# button not displayed while creating html form

Tags: html

```
<body> <div id="div1"> <form id="f1">Personal Information<hr align="right" width="95%"> <div id="div2"><label>Name:</label><input id="text1" type="textbox" placeholder="First Name" size="20"> <input id="text2" type="textbox" placeholder="Last Name" size="20"><br/><br/></div> <div id="div3"><label>E-mail:</label><input id="text3" type="textbox" placeholder="EMail" size="20"><br/><br/></div> <div id="div4"><label>Date Of Birth:</label><input id="text4" type="textbox" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" size="20"><br/><br/></div> <div id="div5"><label>Other Details:</label><textarea id="text5" rows="10" cols="42"  onkeyup=""/></div> <div id="div6"><input type="button" id="button1" value="Submit"></div>
```

but on writing this code button is not displayd what is wrong with the code

Comment: Please, re-format your code.

Answer (score 2):

`Textarea`'s end tag is required.

Replace

```
<textarea id="text5" rows="10" cols="42"  onkeyup=""/>
```

for

```
<textarea id="text5" rows="10" cols="42"  onkeyup=""></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
<input type="button" id="button1" value="Submit">
```

For

```
<input type="submit" id="button1" value="Submit my form !">
```

Comment: `type=button` is valid option.

Answer (score 0):

You missed many tags, I am providing rectified code below.

```
<form id="f1">
  Personal Information
  <hr align="right" width="95%">

  <div id="div2">
    <label>
      Name:
    </label>
    <input id="text1" type="textbox" placeholder="First Name" size="20">

    <input id="text2" type="textbox" placeholder="Last Name" size="20">
    <br/>
    <br/>
  </div>

  <div id="div3">
    <label>
      E-mail:
    </label>
    <input id="text3" type="textbox" placeholder="EMail" size="20">
    <br/>
    <br/>
  </div>

  <div id="div4">
    <label>
      Date Of Birth:
    </label>
    <input id="text4" type="textbox" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" size="20">
    <br/>
    <br/>
  </div>

  <div id="div5">
    <label>
      Other Details:
    </label>
    <textarea id="text5" rows="10" cols="42"  onkeyup="">

    </textarea>
  </div>

  <div id="div6">
    <input type="button" id="button1" value="Submit">
  </div>
</form>
```

You missed Closing tags for Body, Form, Textarea and parent DIV.

Comment: `body` has optional end tag, parent `div` and `form` will be closed automatically in this case. Just close tag for `textarea` is needed here.

Comment: @panther I agree but judging from her question I believe it will be much better to be in habit of closing every tag. Hope you agree with me :)